My class doesn't generate a Fibonacci sequence properly
I'm trying to make a class that generates a Fibonacci sequence. My two modules are below, the fibonacci.py module and the test_fibonacci.py module.  The first two tests pass but the third one seems to fail no matter what I do.  How can I make that pass?  Help me correct this, please.
fibonacci.py code:
class Fibonacci:
    """An iterable for creating a Fibonacci series"""

    def __init__(self, max_count):
        """
        Constructor requires a single positional argument
        which must be an integer.
        """

        self.max_count = max_count  #  Maximum number of iterations
        self.current_count = 0  #  Keeps track of number of Fibonacci numbers generated
        self.current_number = 0  #  Tracks current Fibonacci number
        self.next_number = 1  #  Tracks next Fibonacci number

        #  Raises ValueError for non-integer input
        if not isinstance(max_count, int):
            raise ValueError(f'{max_count} is not an integer.')

    def __iter__(self):
        """Returns the instance of Fibonacci class as an iterator"""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Defines the instance of Fibonacci class as an iterator"""

        # Handles the case where max_count is 0 by returning 0 once
        if self.max_count == 0 and self.current_count == 0:
            self.current_count += 1
            return 0

        #  Stops iteration when the number of iterations equals max_count
        if self.current_count >= self.max_count:
            raise StopIteration

        temp = self.next_number
        self.next_number = self.current_number + self.next_number
        self.current_number = temp
        self.current_count += 1  #  Counter incremented for next iteration
        return self.current_number  # Returns the current Fibonacci number

Here's the code for the test:
import pytest
from fibonacci import Fibonacci

def test_non_integer():
    """Test that non-integer input raises ValueError"""
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        Fibonacci(3.14)

def test_max_count_0():
    """
    Tests that [0] is returned with constructor value of 0
    if cast as a list.
    """
    assert list(Fibonacci(0)) == [0]

def test_max_count_1():
    """
    Tests that [0,1] is returned with constructor value of 1
    if cast as a list.
    """
    assert list(Fibonacci(1)) == [0,1]

Here's the Pytest output:
test_fibonacci.py::test_non_integer PASSED                               [ 33%]
test_fibonacci.py::test_max_count_0 PASSED                               [ 66%]
test_fibonacci.py::test_max_count_1 FAILED                               [100%]
test_fibonacci.py:37 (test_max_count_1)
[1] != [0, 1]

Expected :[0, 1]
Actual   :[1]
<Click to see difference>

def test_max_count_1():
        """
        Tests that [0,1] is returned with constructor value of 1
        if cast as a list.
        """
>       assert list(Fibonacci(1)) == [0,1]
E       assert [1] == [0, 1]
E         
E         At index 0 diff: 1 != 0
E         Right contains one more item: 1
E         
E         Full diff:
E           [
E         -     0,
E               1,
E           ]

test_fibonacci.py:43: AssertionError


Have you tried to see what exactly list(Fibonacci(1)) is? As an additional hint: the iterator yields as many numbers as max_count; why do you expect FIbonacci(1) to yield two numbers?

Please add the relevant Pytest output to the question.

Slow down. Each edit makes your code more wrong. Your first version was correct, your test was wrong. Unless you and I have a very different idea of what Fibonacci and max_count should mean.

Sorry, I've had to go with ctr-z numerous times. max_count is the argument entered.

I know max_count is the argument entered. What I mean is, I understand max_count to mean "maximum count of items yielded". In your first version, Fibonacci(0) yielded zero elements. Fibonacci(1) yielded one element. Fibonacci(4) yielded four. Things made sense. Why should Fibonacci(1), with max_count equal to 1, yield two elements?

The instructions I received for the assignment said that this is one of the test conditions.  Could they maybe be wrong?

In that case, where the requirements clearly contradict the code's semantics, you should post the requirements, or it will be harder for us to help. Because in my mind, the original code was correct (though with one useless check — 0 is handled naturally with self.current_count >= self.max_count — and one missing one — what happens with negative max_count?), just not matching the expectations, whether because the expectations were misunderstood, or illogical in the first place.

Okay, things are starting to make some sense.  The code mostly works but does not add 0 in the sequence of numbers.  What I'm trying to do is to generate 0 as the first number in the sequence.  Other than that, the code works.

To handle 0, capture the current value to return, then calculate the new value.  Return the captured value.  This will pass your tests as shown.
class Fibonacci:
    """An iterable for creating a Fibonacci series"""

    def __init__(self, max_count):
        """
        Constructor requires a single positional argument
        which must be an integer.
        """

        self.max_count = max_count  #  Maximum number of iterations
        self.current_count = 0  #  Keeps track of number of Fibonacci numbers generated
        self.current_number = 0  #  Tracks current Fibonacci number
        self.next_number = 1  #  Tracks next Fibonacci number

        #  Raises ValueError for non-integer input
        if not isinstance(max_count, int):
            raise ValueError(f'{max_count} is not an integer.')

    def __iter__(self):
        """Returns the instance of Fibonacci class as an iterator"""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Defines the instance of Fibonacci class as an iterator"""
        #  Stops iteration when the number of iterations is greater than max_count
        if self.current_count > self.max_count:  # NOTE: change to > from 
            raise StopIteration

        # NOTE: a,b,c = b,c,d is short for a=b; b=c; c=d
        return_value, self.current_number, self.next_number = \
            self.current_number, self.next_number, self.current_number + self.next_number
        self.current_count += 1  #  Counter incremented for next iteration
        return return_value  # Returns the current Fibonacci number

print(list(Fibonacci(0)))
print(list(Fibonacci(1)))
print(list(Fibonacci(5)))

Output:
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]


Thank you!  This worked perfectly! Now I understand where I went wrong.

It looks like there's a misunderstanding between what the code is doing and what the test is expecting. The way max_count is implemented in the original code makes sense—it represents the number of Fibonacci numbers to generate. So, if max_count=1, it should yield [0], not [0, 1]. This aligns with how iterators typically work: they produce a specific number of items, not items up to a certain index.
If the test is expecting [0, 1] for max_count=1, then the test is likely wrong, or the assignment requirements might be unclear. If the requirements explicitly say [0, 1] is the expected output, you'd need to change the logic so that max_count represents the index of the last Fibonacci number instead of the count. But honestly, the original code seems correct based on standard iterator behavior, so it might be worth double-checking the assignment instructions.

I add a solution not far from those showed by the OP by Mark Tolonen. In the answer I speak about production code when I'm referring to the code of the class Fibonacci.
TDD note
In my test code I have added the test test_max_count_2() that on my opinion it is necessary when it is used the TDD to develop the code (I have not used pytest, instead I have used the standard module unittest).
File test_fibonacci.py
import unittest
from fibonacci import Fibonacci

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_max_count_0(self):
        # Tests that [0] is returned with constructor value of 0
        # if cast as a list.
        assert list(Fibonacci(0)) == [0]

    def test_max_count_1(self):
        # Tests that [0,1] is returned with constructor value of 1
        # if cast as a list.
        assert list(Fibonacci(1)) == [0, 1]

    # I have to add this test to complete the method __next__ of the class Fibonacci
    def test_max_count_2(self):
        assert list(Fibonacci(2)) == [0, 1, 1]

    def test_non_integer(self):
        """Test that non-integer input raises ValueError"""
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            Fibonacci(3.14)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


I have showed the test code before the production code because when we use the TDD before we write the test code and after the production code.
Changes in the class Fibonacci
Furthermore in the class Fibonacci I have used 2 attribute (previous_number_1 and previous_number_2) that clarify how the code works.
File fibonacci.py
class Fibonacci:

    def __init__(self, max_count):
        """
        Constructor requires a single positional argument
        which must be an integer.
        """

        self.max_count = max_count  #  Maximum number of iterations
        self.current_count = 0  #  Keeps track of number of Fibonacci numbers generated
        self.current_number = 0  #  Tracks current Fibonacci number
        self.previous_number_1 = 0  # Tracks previous Fibonacci number
        self.previous_number_2 = 0  # Tracks previous Fibonacci number

        #  Raises ValueError for non-integer input
        if not isinstance(max_count, int):
            raise ValueError(f'{max_count} is not an integer.')

    def __iter__(self):
        """Returns the instance of Fibonacci class as an iterator"""
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        """Defines the instance of Fibonacci class as an iterator"""
        #  Stops iteration when the number of iterations is greater than max_count
        if self.current_count > self.max_count:
            raise StopIteration

        if self.current_count <= 1:
            self.current_number = self.current_count
        else:
            self.current_number = self.previous_number_1 + self.previous_number_2
        self.previous_number_2 = self.previous_number_1
        self.previous_number_1 = self.current_number

        self.current_count += 1

        return self.current_number

